# How to force locale for String format for the whole app in Android?

Tags: android

I know that String has a format method which takes Locale as a parameter. I would like to ask if there is a way to force or apply a certain locale to all String formats in the whole app?


I tried `resConfigs` in Gradle but it seems to only work for language, not region. For example, I tried `en_AU` locale on a device with Germany English but it does not display the strings in Australian English.

Comment: `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "AUS"));` One problem still might be that Australia's locale settings are not packed with the java SE. I had once to make Esperanto work.

Comment: Because of this, it is preferable to save strings in resource strings (res/string.xml). When you wish to support more locales in the future, you may manage them with ease.